# Changing the order of the sum in a measure question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, summation

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures which satisfies $\mu_n(X)=1$. I want to show that the function defined as
$$
\nu(E)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\mu_n(E)
$$
is a measure with $\nu(X)=1$.

In the proof of countable additivity part: Let $(E_j)$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$.
$$
\nu(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\mu_n(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu_n(E_j).
$$

If I can change the order of the sum the proof will be finished. Can I do this directly or do I need something more? For example such an observation for all $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\mu_n(E_j)\leq \mu_n(X)=1$.

Comment: You can indeed change the order of the two sums. This is a special case of [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem).

Comment: $\sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_i a_{ij}$ whenever $a_{ij} \ge 0$ (even if each side is $\infty$). No measure theory required for this.